# Saving MDX query results to Table or csv file

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query, mdxstudio, mdxclient

I am not from SSAS background. We are trying to automate a process where we are currently switching multiple filters on excel sheets that are connected to SSAS cubes and do a visual comparison against the data on a Netezza table. Basically, we are validating the results of cubes with the data on Netezza table.

As part of this, we created MDX queries to pull data based on specific filters that we need from cubes. Can we automatically call/execute these MDX queries via bash or Informatica (only ETL tool that we have) and save the results to a csv or a table? Please ignore my zero knowledge SQL Server technologies and appreciate any guidance in this regards.

Thank you!

Comment: Explain what you have tried.

Comment: Are you able to use VBA in the Excel spreadsheet? That may be able to send execute MDX queries with ADOMD, but it is a lot to learn if you've not done VB or cubes before!